# How to bind chosen.js to inner HTML?

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I want to bind the chosen.js script to the inner HTML generated combo box. When the user clicks add description a table is generated where the user can select employee names. I want the chosen.js to work on that.

```
function addjobdesc() {
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.className = 'row';

div.innerHTML = '
<table id="tblObs" name="tblObs" width="70%"  bgcolor="#CCCCCC">

<td colspan="5"><b>Job Description (Work Ppermit/ Activity)</b></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#33CC00"><td ><center> <b>Exact Location</b> </center></td> 
<td><b><center>Permit Initiated By<br />/<br />Activity Supervised by</center></b></td>

<select id="j_d_permit_by" class="usersuggest" name="j_d_permit_by[]" >
<option value="0">Select User</option>
<?php  
$users = getUserS(); 
while($usersss = mysql_fetch_array($users)){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $usersss[0];?>">
<?php echo $usersss[4]." ".$usersss[5];  ?>
</option><?php } ?>


var config = {
                  '.usersuggest'           : {},
                  '.usersuggest-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
                  '.usersuggest-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
                  '.usersuggest-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
                  '.usersuggest-width'     : {width:"45%"}
                }
for (var selector in config) {
                  $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
                }

document.getElementById('job_desc').appendChild(div);
}
```

Right now the table is being generated but the chosen.js doesnt work on this. Looking forward to your advice. Thanks.

Comment: Nope. Although now even the table is not generating when I click the button to add one.

Comment: This code has `errors`. You are not properly handling the quotation marks..

Comment: @SahibUzZaman I'm pretty sure there **are** errors. Did you press F12 to open the devtools in your browser and look in the console tab there?

Comment: No, there are no erros pertaining to the code mentioned above.